# Exporting encrypted SNMPv3 traps to JSON with TShark

Tags: wireshark, snmp, tshark

I have a pcap file with recordings of encrypted SNMPv3 traps from Wireshark (Version 3.2.2). For analyzing the traps, I want to export the protocol data to json using *tshark*.

```
tshark.exe -T ek -Y "snmp" -P -V -x -r input.pcap > output.json
```

Currently, I supply the infos to decrypt the packages via the "snmp_users" file in *C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\Wireshark*.

```
# This file is automatically generated, DO NOT MODIFY.
,"snmp_user","SHA1","xxxxxx","AES","yyyyyyy"
```

Is it possible to supply the options via commandline?

I have tried:

```
tshark.exe -T ek -Y "snmp" -P -V -x -o "snmp.users_table.username:snmp_user" ...
```

But that causes an error:

```
tshark: -o flag "snmp.users_table.username:snmp_user" specifies unknown preference
```

Update 16.09.2020:
Option -Y used instead of -J:

> **-Y|--display-filter** 
> Cause the specified filter (which uses the syntax of read/display
> filters, rather than that of capture filters) to be applied before
> printing a decoded form of packets or writing packets to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the option as a *User Access Table* or `uat`, with the specific table being the name of the file, namely **snmp_users**.  So, for example:

On Windows:

```
tshark.exe -o "uat:snmp_users:\"\",\"snmp_user\",\"SHA1\",\"xxxxxx\",\"AES\",\"yyyyyyy\"" -T ek -J "snmp" -P -V -x -r input.pcap > output.json
```

And on *nix:

```
tshark -o 'uat:snmp_users:"","snmp_user","SHA1","xxxxxx","AES","yyyyyyy"' -T ek -J "snmp" -P -V -x -r input.pcap > output.json
```

Unfortunately, the Wireshark documentation is currently lacking in describing the `uat` option.  There is a Google Summer of Code project underway though, of which Wireshark is participating, so perhaps documentation will be improved here.

Comment: Yes, a better documentation would be awesome.

Comment: Thank you, Christopher! Your solution works. I have checked again. It doesn't leave behind plain text passwords like the Wireshark GUI using "User Table" option from the Protocol Preferences.